# Commerce Kickstart - Show breadcrumbs on account/profile pages

Tags: commerce, breadcrumbs

How display the breacrumbs on all account pages (user/*)?

In Kickstart distribution of Drupal Commerce, the breadcrumbs is hidden by default on this pages.

I have try to set position for the breacrumbs block (disabled by default), it's correctly displayed on all pages but it's displayed duplicate as you can see.

What's the good way for this?

Edit: Adding a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate on which page? You can show that default block only to certain path

Comment: "as you can see" were you planning to add a screenshot?

Comment: I'm sorry for delay, it's now added! :d